# Swap between first and last elements in an array, and then remove the last element

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array, I need to swap between first and last elements, and then remove the last element.

Can I safely use `arr[0] = arr.pop()`?

The reason I'm asking is that the RHS of this expression changes `arr`, and then the entire expression changes `arr` again.

Can this possibly lead to some sort of undefined behavior (if this term even applies for JavaScript)?

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Sorry, I'm saving the first aside (for later use), then putting the last where the first is, and then removing the last (repeating the process until the array is empty).

Comment: No - JS is single-threaded so you won't have synchronisation issues, and the construct is fine as long `arr` isn't empty. There is no undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Amadan: It's not about multi-threading or concurrency or anything like that. I just know that similar expressions in native languages like C and C++ are sometimes undefined by the language standard. For example, `++i = i++`.

Comment: I have to wonder what your use case is for what seems like a slightly odd form of array manipulation

Comment: @Alnitak: It is likely faster than splicing a mid-element out, as long as you just want it out and don't care about maintaining order of the other elements.

Comment: @Alnitak: See my first comment above (for someone who asked a similar question, then apparently deleted it).

Comment: @goodvibration is your use case just optimisation?

Comment: To be fair, you just repeated _what_ you are doing in that comment, not why. "Why are you eating spoon with a fork? - Because I need to move the soup from the bowl into my mouth." :) As to why, I can only see two reasons: either performance, or it is really important for some reason to move the whole array through the first element. I am almost sure it's the former, but you never know.

Comment: 1.  no, there's no UB.   2.  it feels like premature optimisation to be manipulating the array like this.    Why remove the elements at all?

Comment: @Amadan: I need to handle all the elements in a particular order, dictated by the method of swapping the last with the first at every iteration until the array is empty. This particular order is important, because it is implemented on a remote system which I test using a local process which executes my Javascript code.

Comment: @Alnitak: See comment above.

Comment: There are almost certainly ways to achieve the desired order without actually changing the array's contents (or length).

Answer (score -1):

Answer:

This method fails when the array size is 1, hence whether or not it is safe is irrelevant.

Comment: @Amadan: Yes, but then again, one measly piece of code of the same length and complexity (i.e., a "standard swap") can replace the entire method.